# What mode to work on when texture painting - Solid / Lookdev / Rendered mode in EEVEE?

Tags: rendering, texture-painting

Im creating a game asset, and i want to export it to Unity later on. So i have started texture painting this object, but as you can see it looks different when rendered compared to solid or look dev mode. I dont know which mode i should stick to when texture painting to get the most accurate colors. I guess rendered more is the best one because it will be the final render with all the lighting and etc but even though i have 3 sun lights it still looks dark compared to look dev mode (which  i prefer over rendered mode) but if its going to look really dark in a game engine as well then Im not sure which mode to stick to to see the real color/lights when texture painting. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should paint in lookdev mode, making sure texture paint opacity is set to 0 to be able to see your full material when painting.

Comment: So i will continue to use lookdev mode then. Where can I access texture paint opacity? And Is it too late to change it at this stage, do i have to restart my texture paint?

Comment: In the overlay options. No you can switch modes freely.

Comment: thankyou so much!